# How to set the liquid level for a lava block? Bukkit 1.15.2 plugin

Tags: plugins, liquid, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make it so that any time a player breaks a certain block, lava will be spawned at that block. But i don't want the spawned lava to be a source block. How do i do this? I've tried everything and if there was just one simple solution it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Please post your attempt. Do you know how to do it if it were a source block?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried it by myself, but I assume you can place the block and change the BlockData afterwards. Just get the BlockData with [getBlockData()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/Block.html#getBlockData--) cast it to a [Levelled](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/data/Levelled.html) and change the level value and assign the [Levelled](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/data/Levelled.html) to the block again. Please check out the documentation of [Levelled](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/data/Levelled.html), the value you need to choose isn't intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

As Geist 5000 said:

> I didn't tried it by myself, but I assume you can place the block and change the BlockData afterwards. Just get the BlockData with getBlockData() cast it to a Levelled and change the level value and assign the Levelled to the block again. Please check out the documentation of Levelled, the value you need to choose isn't intuitive.

You can modify the `BlockData` cast it into `Levelled` and set the level there:

```
public void setLavaBlock(Location location, int level) {
        Block target = location.getBlock();
        target.setType(Material.LAVA);
        Levelled blockData = (Levelled) target.getBlockData();
        blockData.setLevel(level);
        target.setBlockData(blockData);
}
```